# Spring Security authentication ignoring password

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

In my project I have implemented Spring Security. It's checking whether username and password is correct or not. I want to authenticate only username but not password. How can I achieve this?

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    if (lan == null) {
    //  loadPasswordRules();
    }

    List<UserDetails> users = loadUsersByUsername(username);
    if (users.size() == 0) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Username "  + username +  " is invalid ");
    }

    UserDetails user = users.get(0); // contains no IRole[]
    /** Raising exception since start and expiry of user is not valid.  */
    /** Raising exception since start and expiry of user is not valid.  */
    Date todayDate = new Date();
    if ( !((todayDate).after(((User) user).getStartDate()) && (todayDate).before(((User) user).getExpiryDate())) ) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("User " + username + " account is expired.");
        /* throw new LockedException("User " + username + " account is expired.");
           throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User {" + username + "} account is expired."); SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message */
    }

    /*if ( ((User) user).getLastSuccessLogin() != null) {
        Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        newDate.setTime( todayDate );
        newDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, - lan.intValue());
        Calendar oldDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        oldDate.setTime( ((User) user).getLastSuccessLogin() );
        if (newDate.after(oldDate)) {  
            lockUserAccount(username);
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("User " + username + " account is expired.");
        }
    }*/

    Set<IRole> dbAuthsSet = new HashSet<IRole>();
    if (enableAuthorities) {
        dbAuthsSet.addAll(loadUserAuthorities(user.getUsername()));
    }
    List<IRole> dbAuths = new ArrayList<IRole>(dbAuthsSet);
    if (dbAuths.size() == 0) {
         throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Username " + username + " has no assigned roles.");
    }
    ((User) user).setRoles(dbAuths);
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this creating a custom `AuthenticationProvider` implementation and configure your `AuthenticationManager` to use that.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `Custom Filter` to due with this. The `Filter` should extends class `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and return a `Custom Authentication` object. Then the `Authentication Provider` will see it and do check only username which is return by the `Filter`. After completing everything, you must do configure the `Filter` to Spring Security context to make it works.

You also can see my complete example here : http://phuonghuynh.github.io/java/spring/security/2015/09/06/spring-security-multiple-authentication-providers.html